# In D3 v4, how do I align axes appropriately?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 v4.  I have a bar graph created with an x-axis using `scaleBand()`.  Now, I have created a y-axis but my issue is that no matter how I position it, it is cutting into the actual bars of the graph.

[image]

At the top of my JS file, I have:

var width = 350;
   var height = 300;

Then, the part where I actually create the Y-axis:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 300000])
      .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y);
            yAxis.ticks(6);

chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - dist_from_right) + ", 0)")
     .call(yAxis);
```

As you can see from the picture, the axis stretches the entirety of the height of the SVG, from bottom to top meaning that half of the 0 gets cut off and half off the 300,000 gets cut off.

First question: how do I "squish" (or scale) the y-axis so that it displays within the confines of the SVG?

Next, I want to translate the y-axis so that it is not cutting into my red bar.  If I try to use the `transform` attribute, I can push the axis far to the right of the SVG borders but that means the numbers are off the SVG boundary.  I've also tried to increase the `width` variable but that does nothing because it just stretches out the x-axis proportionally.

Second question: how do I move the y-axis so that it is not cutting into the x-axis and red bar and also remains visible in the SVG window?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should create a [mcve]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D3, axes are positioned according to the `range` of corresponding scales. So, you need a "padding" for the ranges. Right now, as your range goes from `0` to `height` (or vice versa, it doesn't matter), the axis starts at the very beginning of the SVG and ends at its very end.

I see you have a `dist_from_right`, but I don't know what are you doing with it in your x scale. So, for now, let's suppose you don't have any padding.

First, let's set the paddings:

```
var paddingLeft = 10, paddingRight = 10, paddingTop = 10, paddingBottom = 10;
```

Here, 10 is just a given number, change it accordingly.

After that, set the ranges using the paddings:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 300000])
  .rangeRound([height - paddingBottom, paddingTop]);
```

The same for your x scale:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, someValue])
  .rangeRound([paddingLeft, width - paddingRight]);
```

Then you define the axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);//the same for the y axis
```

Having the ranges with the paddings, call the axes setting that paddings:

```
chart.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - paddingRight) + ", 0)")
 .call(yAxis);
```

And the same for the x axis:

```
chart.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - paddingBottom) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);
```

Here is a working example. I made the SVG light gray and the plotting area white, so you can see the paddings.:

```js
var paddingLeft = 20, paddingRight = 40, paddingTop = 10, paddingBottom = 40;

var width = 300, height = 300;

var chart = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

chart.append("rect")
  .attr("x", paddingLeft)
  .attr("y", paddingTop)
  .attr("width", width - paddingLeft - paddingRight)
  .attr("height", height - paddingTop - paddingBottom)
  .attr("fill", "white");

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .rangeRound([height - paddingBottom, paddingTop]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .rangeRound([paddingLeft, width - paddingRight]);

var yAxis = d3.axisRight(y);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - paddingRight) + ", 0)")
     .call(yAxis);

chart.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - paddingBottom) + ")")
     .call(xAxis);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is perfect and solved my issue.  Thank you so much for your help!